# Linux can bus driver

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, can-bus

I am going through a can base network driver for MCP-2515
https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-3.6.y/drivers/net/can/mcp251x.c

Please suggest where i can find the description of the function, :--

```
alloc_candev
open_candev
alloc_can_skb
can_dropped_invalid_skb
alloc_can_err_skb
etc .....
```

Is there some read-me file or some tutorial ?

Please suggest.

Comment: I am not fully clear about your question. about variou  API used in writing the CAN driver can find on this link. http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~pisa/can/doc/lincandoc-0.3.pdf

Comment: this is relate to RT-linux driver.

Comment: In the above link "Linux/RT-Linux CAN Driver" every API is properly defined. You can also see  "can/dev.h" in cross-reference as answered below.

Answer (score 1):

For kernel functions I have found
[lxr](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.8.5/include/linux/can/dev.h#L98)
very useful. But I am not that this is what you are asking for, perhaps you could be a little more specific in your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the first place to look for info about SocketCAN drivers: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/can.txt

Networking stuff can be found in the same folder: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/

Here a description of network buffering in Linux: http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/skb.html and http://www.tldp.org/LDP/khg/HyperNews/get/net/net-intro.html